# EditText with long default text on a single line

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `EditText` that I am trying to set with a very long, unbreaking text value (a URL), but even with the following XML declaration, the text is breaking to a second line.

```
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/address" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:maxLines="1"
android:hint="Enter URL"
android:text="http://www.example.com/news/2010-07-15/this-is-the-story-title-here.html">
</EditText>
```

I've tried the solutions here (adding `android:ellipsize="end"`), but it made no difference. Reducing the text in length to something no more than the length of the `EditText` worked... but this is realistic for a URL `EditText`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Comment: android:scrollHorizontally seemed to do it. Any idea how to NOT have the EditText selected by default with the cursor at the end when an Activity is started via XML?

Comment: 1. you should accept my answer 2. you could have another view in the layout and request focus to it..

Comment: Well I wasn't sure that it was the 'most correct one' that was going to come in, as it suggests using a deprecated property, and the results include the text in the EditText being scrolled all the way horizontally to the end, which is less than optimal.

Comment: If you want to edit the answer to remove the android:singleLine property, I can mark it as the answer for now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding `android:singleLine="true"` to the mix

```
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/address" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLines="1"
android:hint="Enter URL"
android:text="http://www.example.com/news/2010-07-15/this-is-the-story-title-here.html">
</EditText>
```

Comment: android:singleLine is deprecated, per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine

Comment: Interesting, google seems to have conflicting docs. It is not listed as deprecated here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3asingleLine Perhaps they should update it. In the mean time, does setting scroll horizontally to true help?

Answer (score 1):

Use value for the attribute `inputType` other than `textMultiLine`. The attribute `singleLine` is deprecated.