# EditText's hint gets cut off because my hint text is longer than one line. The editText only displays one line. How can I make the whole hint visible?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

EditText's hint gets cut off because my hint text is longer than one line. The editText only displays one line. How can I make the whole hint visible?

This is the editText that gives me troubles.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/pin" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:inputType="number"
         android:hint="@string/pinhintadmin"
         android:maxLength="4"
         android:layout_margin="10dip"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
```

Here is my whole xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background1" >  
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/burr"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/flob" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/buildingnameandaddress"
         android:inputType="textCapWords"
         android:layout_margin="10dip"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>


     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/appartment"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>

     <EditText android:id="@+id/txtName" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/hintapp"
         android:layout_margin="10dip"
         android:inputType="textCapSentences"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Pin:"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>

     <EditText android:id="@+id/pin" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:inputType="number"
         android:hint="@string/pinhintadmin"
         android:maxLength="4"
         android:layout_margin="10dip"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>

     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/username"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dip"/>

     <EditText android:id="@+id/txtEmail" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:inputType="textCapWords"
         android:layout_margin="10dip"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/password"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>

     <EditText android:id="@+id/registerPassword" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dip"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:text="@string/registerbtnadmin"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:background="@drawable/button_red"
         android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color" />

     <!--  Error message -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/register_error"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#e30000"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
     </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is @string/pinhintadmin?

Comment: Something long that takes about two lines. It's not really relevant, it's not in english and it's just a random string, nothing special.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767736/edittext-with-long-default-text-on-a-single-line)

Or
You can try this

```
view.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<small><small><small>" + 
         getString(R.string.hint) + "</small></small></small>"));
```

as accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203477/android-edittext-hint)

Comment: That did not work. It works I guess for when the text is long, but my text is not long, just the hint is very long.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` in your XML:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:autofillHints="personName"
    android:background="@null"
    android:hint="Enter first name"
    android:maxLength="25"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a long line of string for the hint of the eddittext you can put a `new line character` to the place where the new line occurs

**sample:**

```
 android:hint="first line \n second line"
```

Comment: I could do that but I would not be sure where to enter the line break, for smaller screens it would break too soon and for bigger ones too late. I think I could just give up on having a long hint instead.

Comment: @JeromeWasBannedBySONazis use your values folder instead. for smaller screen and biggers screens.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `\n` in the string.
`<string name="pinhintadmin">line one \n line two </string>`

or try using `android:scrollHorizontally="true"`